# Cloaking the USS Enterprise

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, cloaking

While the Romulans and Klingons have cloaking technology, do any of the Federation ships have it?
It seems that the USS Enterprise more than once is surprised by a cloaked ship. But why have they never developed it for their ship?