# Star Trek TNG episode with three timelines and a trial about mankind's right to exist

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

After reading the question [Cloaking the USS Enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/cloaking-the-uss-enterprise), I'm trying to remember an episode of *TNG*.

- It seems to run 3 different timelines in parallel, Current-time
  past time and future time.
- They all do some sort of scan at a specific spot in space, and this
  causes some kind of effect to happen backwards in time, threatening
  to prevent the formation of human life.
- Q was involved.
- There was a trial, about mankind's right to exist.

What brought it to mind was the *Enterprise* of the future, I think it had 3 warp nacelles... and maybe a cloak... but that's going to be a separate question once I get the episode :-)

Comment: Woah, Google is good: http://www.google.com/search?q=star+trek+episode+with+three+time+lines+scan+trial I’m impressed.

Comment: fair enough, not my best question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's ["All Good Things"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)), the series finale of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.

The trial refers back to the series' pilot episode, ["Encounter at Farpoint"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Encounter_at_Farpoint).